# How to set MongoClientOptions using a MongoClientURI?

Tags: java, mongodb

In the current MongoDB Java API (3.0), there is not a `MongoClient` constructor that accepts a `MongoClientURI` and a `MongoClientOptions` [1]. How I set the options for a client built using a URI?

Is there a way to convert a `MongoClientURI` to a `List<ServerAddress>` ?
Or set the options after construction of the client? The `MongoClient(mongoURI).setOptions(options)` accepts an int. The documentation for this method doesn't explain what that int is supposed to be [2]

[1] http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html

[2] http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/Mongo.html#setOptions-int-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can use [this variant](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientURI.html#MongoClientURI-java.lang.String-com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions.Builder-) of the `MongoClientURI` constructor that takes a `String` URI and a [`MongoClientOptions.Builder`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.Builder.html) that has methods for setting each option.

Then you can create your `MongoClient` using the constructor that takes a `MongoClientURI`.